# changing authentication of local storage token to PHPSESSID - android studio - kotlin

Tags: kotlin, redirect, android-webview

**vm.token** is the authentication for the android application that i also want to use on the webview authentication.

```
override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                                    isRedirecting.value = true
                                    view?.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('token','${vm.token}');")

                                }
```

**Tried this method it only redirect to the site but not storing the cookies**

```
override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                                    isRedirecting.value = true
                                    view?.loadUrl("javascript:cookies.setItem('PHPSESSID','${vm.token}');")
                                }
```

**Also tried this function but still not working**

```
override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                                    if (url == "https://portal.developer.com/") {
                                        // Use JavaScript to set a session cookie for the URL.
                                        val sessionCookieScript = "document.cookie = 'PHPSESSID=${vm.token}; SameSite=None; Secure';"
                                        view?.evaluateJavascript(sessionCookieScript, null)
                                    }
                                    isRedirecting.value = true
                                }
```